# Redirect to a page without changing the url - but AFTER another RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a **multidomain solution** with the following setup:

- both domains **subdomain1.domain.com** and **subdomain2.domain.com** point to the **same directory on the server**
- if one visits the URL https://subdomain1.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article he should be redirected to https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article
- this cannot be solved with a simple redirect, as https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article does not exist
- because **subdomain1.domain.com** and **subdomain2.domain.com** point to the same directory, https://subdomain1.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article is identical to https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article, but it is needed to "mask" the second one in order to show only https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article - therefore not changing the URL on the second RewriteRule

So far I tried many different rules & combinations, getting closest to a solution with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomain-category/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-category/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

...which works so far.

Now, what is missing are the rules that show the content of the page https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article while the URL in the address bar of the browser should read https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article.

Thanks in advance for any valuable hint/info!

Comment: entering through https://subdomain1.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article

Comment: "except that `https://subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article` remains on the URL" - But you stated you are requesting `subdomain1`? And the rule you've posted would strip `/subdomain-category`. What other rules do you have? How is this request ultimately handled/routed?

Comment: yes, I am requesting subdomain1, this should redirect to subdomain2 as explained above (bulletpoint 2)

Comment: maybe I am thinking it too complicated and there is a much simpler solution I am not seeing right now? one which can completely ignore my rules above?

Comment: Why do you have `R=301` rule when you just want to show `subdomain1.domain.com` to your visitors?

Comment: as explained above, both domains should be visible to the visitors, but subdomain2 ONLY to those visiting subdomain1.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article

Comment: But the output you are seeing is not consistent with the directives you've posted, hence my comment above. The second rule (by itself) does not redirect the request, so what other directives do you have? How is this request being handled? It doesn't look like `/subdomain-category/subdomain-article` maps to a file, so you must have other directives - and it's quite likely you have a conflict. (Also make sure you are not seeing a cached redirect/response. 301s are cached persistently by the browser and can make testing problematic. Use 302s instead for testing.)

Comment: @MrWhite there is a CMS behind it, maybe I should have mentioned it. .../subdomain-article is a file/article. there are no other directives, except those from standard cms. what is bugging me is, that line1-3 work as intended, it is redirecting subdomain1.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article to subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article but since this doesnt exist, I need another rule rewriting subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article to subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-category/subdomain-article but while keeping the URL subdomain2.domain.com/subdomain-article on the browsers addressbar

Comment: @MrWhite BTW: thanks for pointing out the 301 caching, it was driving me mad while testing!

Comment: I changed the content of the post in order to maybe make it easier to understand